# How to make List<List<List<String>>> based on two List<Map> dart

Tags: dart

I have a `List<Map>` with key values:

```
              "column-data": [
                {
                  "label": "Title",
                  "align": "right",
                  "width": 50,
                },
                
                {
                  "label": "Description",
                  "align": "left",
                  "width": 100,
                }
              ],
```

I have another `List<Map>` :

```
 "row-data": [
                {
                  "title": "Subscription #1",                
                  "description": "Lorem ipsum dolar set amit."
                },
                {
                  "title": "Subscription #2",
                  "description": "Lorem ipsum dolar set amit."
                }
              ]
```

My question how do i add key values `align` and `width` from `column-data` based on `label` and `row-data` key values together inside a `List<List<List<String>>>`. I want to add for each `row-data` the meta data from `column-data` like example below:

```
  "row-data" : [
   
   [
     ["Subscription #1", "right", "50"], 
     ["Lorem ipsum dolar set amit.","left", "100"]
   ],
   [
     ["Subscription #2", "right", "50"], 
     ["Lorem ipsum dolar set amit.","left", "100"]
   ]
   
 ];
```

**Edit**

There is actually a possibility that `align` or `width` in a map from `column-data` won't exist. Is there a way to resolve that issue? –

`title`, `description`, `Title` and `Description` are dynamic and so there can be different key and key value names. Is there a way to not specify those key and values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do what basically constitutes to a sql join to join the entries of each row item to the different columns and build up your lists.

```
const columnData = [
  {
    "label": "Title",
    "align": "right",
    "width": 50,
  },
  {
    "label": "Description",
    "align": "left",
    "width": 100,
  }
];
const rowData = [
  {
    "title": "Subscription #1",                
    "description": "Lorem ipsum dolar set amit."
  },
  {
    "title": "Subscription #2",
    "description": "Lorem ipsum dolar set amit.",
    "something": "or other"
  }
];

final newRowData = rowData.map(
  (r) => r.entries.map(
    (re) {
      final col = columnData.firstWhere(
        (c) => re.key.toUpperCase() == (c['label'] as String).toUpperCase(),
        orElse: () => {}
      );
      return [re.value, ...[
        for (final ce in col.entries)
          if (ce.key != 'label')
            ce.value.toString()
      ]];
    }
  ).toList()
).toList();
```

You don't show any examples of what should happen if no columns match up, so this would just omit those parts.

```
[
  [
    ["Subscription #1", "right", "50"],
    ["Lorem ipsum dolar set amit.", "left", "100"]
  ],
  [
    ["Subscription #2", "right", "50"],
    ["Lorem ipsum dolar set amit.", "left", "100"],
    ["or other"]
  ]
]
```

Comment: There is actually a possibility that  `align` or `width` in a map from `column-data` won't exist. Is there a way to resolve that issue?

Comment: `title`, `description`, `Title` and `Description` are also dynamic and so there can be different key and key value names. Is there a way to not specify those key and values?

Comment: Well you'll have to change the approach a bit then, but it isn't that much different. I suppose the point is to go through the entries of all the rows and try to match them up to a column and add the column data.